# CodeIgniter - Reading Excel File

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I am developing this script that accepts students scores and i want every part of the calculations to be done in excel before uploading it to the website. I have been able to get everything working except that when i try to read a cell that has formulas using phpExcel, it gets the formula instead of the actual value

**Controller**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Excel_file extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Excel');
}
public function index()
{
    $file = './files/test.xlsx';

    $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
    $obj = $reader->load($file);
    // $worksheet = $obj->getActiveSheet();
    $worksheet = $obj->getSheet(2);
    $lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();

    echo "<table>";

    for ($row=2; $row <=$lastRow; $row++) { 
        echo "<tr> 
                 <td>";
                    echo $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $worksheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();

                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $worksheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();

        echo     "</td>
              </tr>";


    }
    echo "</table>";
}

}
```

Comment: Try using `getFormattedValue()` instead of `getValue()`.

Comment: great! it working fine now... Thank You